# Select two results while using Group By in a sqlite request

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, select, group-by

It is tricky to explain, so lets start with an example:

I have a sqlite table containing multiple fields (**id**, **language**, **title**, **etc.**)

For one single title, they maybe several languages.

```
id --  language  --    title          --   publication  --  etc.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  --    Eng     --  Les misérables   --      1968      --  ...
2  --    Fr      --  Les misérables   --      1985      --  ...
3  --    Fr      --  Les misérables   --      2001      --  ...
4  --    Eng     --  Brave new world  --      1975      --  ...
5  --    Eng     --  Brave new world  --      1999      --  ...
6  --    Fr      --  Brave new world  --      1999      --  ...
```

**My problem:**

I would like in only one SELECT request to get the first result in English and in French.

```
SELECT (id WHERE language='Eng') AS id1, (id WHERE language='Fr') AS id2 FROM myTable GROUP BY title
```

To continue the example the request would give as a result

```
// this is javascript but the problem is about the sql part
results.rows.item(1).id1 = 1
results.rows.item(1).id2 = 2

results.rows.item(2).id1 = 4
results.rows.item(2).id2 = 6

etc.
```

Of course the syntax above is wrong, but is it possible to do in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start with a correct syntax example:

```
SELECT title
FROM myTable
GROUP BY title
```

Here you have all rows of the Table *myTable* grouped by Title, e.g.

```
| title | id      | language            | ...
| 'Foo' | [1,4,6] | ['en', 'ger', 'fr'] | ...
| 'Bar' | [2,5]   | ['en', 'it']        | ...
...
```

The values in [] represents the groups that are produced by *GROUP BY*.

If you're just interested in the ids, you can apply the group_concat operation on column id

```
SELECT title, group_concat(id)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY title
```

This will give you for every title a column with comma-seperated list of ids (see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html )
You could also `SELECT ... group_concat(language)` and reassemble id and language on the client, if you need both information.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 SELECT
     (SELECT id From myTable WHERE language='Eng') AS id1, 
     (SELECT id From myTable WHERE language='Fr') AS id2,
     title
     FROM myTable GROUP BY title
```

You can do this when Subquery returned exact  1 value other wise you got error.

Comment: This just works, if you know that there are just these two languages. If you can be sure, this is fine.

Comment: Thx. Yes I do have only two language. I am trying to make it work. :)